Proving (not inferring) Dirac Eq. 27.4 in "GTR" involving variation of the matter current
Dirac infers (but does not derive) Eq. 27.4 in his GTR text. Here $p^\mu$ is the matter current (momentum) four vector, and we have the conservation law $\partial_\mu p^\mu = 0$. Dirac varies the position of a small element of matter from $z^\mu \to z^\mu + b^\mu$ and infers that
$$\delta p^\mu = (p^\nu b^\mu - p^\mu b^\nu)_{,\nu}.$$
This question was asked and "answered" here:
How to derive equation 27.4 in Dirac's "General Theory of Relativity" book?
but I confess that I cannot make heads or tails of the answer that was offered. I'm sure there must be something there, but a combination of incomprehensible notation and explication renders it totally opaque. I'm sure the fault is mine. However, I would be very grateful if someone could provide a clearer, simpler, or alternative explanation.

It would be helpful if you elaborated on which part of that answer you find unsatisfactory or confusing. I added a comment just now answering the question you asked.

Thanks @J.Murray, I saw your comment and responded.
